# Postgresql can't be access from outside of host

Tags: postgresql

I have setup my postgresql and got this while running: `netstat -peanut`

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      109        13704       -
```

My `postgresql.conf` file has the configuration :

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

My `pg_hba.conf` file contains the below line:

```
host    all             all             192.168.103.0/24        md5
```

And my network configuration after running `ifconfig -a` is :

```
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:0d:a1:94  
inet addr:192.168.103.226  Bcast:192.168.103.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe0d:a194/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:12320 errors:0 dropped:26 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:44 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
```

But while connecting from my host(192.168.103.22) pgadmin III to postgresql to that host, there is no hit on running postgresql server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What the error you get while connecting?

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon while connecting , this doesn't hit on server.

Comment: What the error you get while connecting?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe can't connect with the given data (general information of pgadmin). I am sure that I have given the correct name of user and correct password.

Comment: Then please tell what you entered in the "Create Server..." dialog, and in which input field. A screenshot might suffice.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Create Server or Connecting to Server ?

Comment: "Create server...". Or alternatively, open the "Properties" and tell us what's there.

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall, see if you allowed connection on 5432, if so change md5 to trust, just for testing !

Comment: This didn't help. :(

Comment: Emm, if you're running linux turn off your fw : 
 service iptables stop
and try aguin.
 use :
netstat -tulpn | grep 5432 
 see if the port listen !

Comment: Sorry i didn't notice that you did that !

Comment: Try 
"host    all             all             (ip@ from where you try to connect)/32        trust"
then do a reload !